# Android Facebook API V 2.5, How to get User details?

Tags: android, facebook

From below code I can able to get User name and Id but not any other information like gender mail ID etc.., Can I get any link relate to Android.

```
Request request = Request.newMeRequest(
                Session.getActiveSession(),
                new Request.GraphUserCallback() 
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                            Response response) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Log.d(TAG,"user  "+user);
                    }
                });

         Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
```

Comment: Could you please give any link related to Android.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph#userdata

Comment: thanks, CBroe, this is working